# Trying to create object for dict,

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to pass values for the address field, as dict value. and it is a foreign key field to the employee.

```
address = request.data.get('address', '')
add = Address.objects.create(area=address.area, street=address.street, city=address.city, state=address.state, pincode=address.pincode)
add.save()
```

I am getting error dict has no attribute area

Answer (score 0):

It's a dict and not object. So you can't access it with dot notation, you should fetch values using it's keys.

```
address = request.data.get('address', None)

if address:
    add = Address.objects.create(
        area=address["area"],
        street=address["street"],
        city=address["city"],
        state=address["state"],
        pincode=address["pincode"])
    add.save()
```

You can also use python shorthand.

```
add = Address.objects.create(**address)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but how should I add these values to the employee model because it is a foreign key for the employee model.

Comment: Can you please show your models ? [Maybe  `Employee.objects.create(address=add)`]

Comment: class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)

Comment: I want to serialize the object and display that,

Comment: employee = Employee.create_employee(email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile_number, dob, gender, nationality, department, skill, address)
            serializer = EmployeeListSerializer(data=employee)
except:
            return Response({"success": False, "message": "An error occurredPlease try again"},
                  status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
  return Response({"success": True, "profile": serializer.initial_data,"token": employee.get_token()})                                                                                                     for this

Comment: I think we're now going off topic w.r.t this question. If this answer works https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and please open a new question for serialiser, will be happy help.